# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive in deck class

Tags: java

I'm making a card game and I'm getting the error that n must be positive. I did some research and it means that (cards.size) is equal or less than 0 I believe, but I don't understand how to make my code work, something must be wrong.

Code:

```
public class Deck
{
public ArrayList <Card> cards;
Deck()
{
    cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int a = 0; a < 52; a++)
    {           
            cards.add(new Card(a));         
    }
}

public Card PlayerCardDraw ()
{
    Random generator = new Random ();
    int index = generator.nextInt (cards.size ());
    return cards.remove (index);

}
```

How can I fix my array list so i don't get this error? it relates back to Card so I'll post that code too, I know something isn't right in my Card class but I don't know if that's the problem or not.

```
public class Card
{
int c = 52;
int cardpath[] = new int[c];

Card ()
{

}


public Card(int c)
{
    this.c = c;
}

public int getCardPath()
{
return cardpath[c];
}   
}
```

Error message:

```
java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source) at Cards.Deck.PlayerCardDraw(Deck.java:21)
line 21 is int index = generator.nextInt (cards.size ());
```

EDIT: I did what Nankumar Tekale said and it's saying what you guys predicted: It's drawing more than 52 cards. What I don't understand is the error is popping up at

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        C = deck.P1CardDraw ();
        card [cardNum].draw (i*75+100, 400); //Error line
        cardNum++;                   
    }
```

my P1CardDraw() class

```
public ArrayList < Card > p1Hand;
public ArrayList < Card > P1CardDraw ()
{

    p1Hand = new ArrayList < > ();
    p1Hand.add (PlayerCardDraw ());
    return p1Hand;
}
```

Comment: Where is it giving you the error? Can you post the error message/stack trace?

Comment: cards = new ArrayList<>(); should be ArrayList <Card>(); I guess.

Comment: @Adio thats type inference, it'd work in java 7, however < java7 its a compiler error

Comment: @iamnotmaynard at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Cards.Deck.PlayerCardDraw(Deck.java:21) line 21 is  int index = generator.nextInt (cards.size ());

Comment: @Hitman47 i do not know how to call a constructor in its own class

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error message. How many times does `PlayerCardDraw()` get called?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan acutally i did try your case and it works...so i tried new Deck().PlayerCardDraw ();

Comment: It seems there is other code we might need to see, but my guess is `PlayerCardDraw()` is being called too many times, emptying out `cards` and causing `0` to be sent to `nextInt()`.

Comment: Instead of drawing randomly, you could simply shuffle the deck: `Collections.shuffle(cards);`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard right now it's called through another arraylist for the player's hand and it is used in a for statement for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)

Comment: @assylias after shuffling it how could i use that to generate a random number(index) to be removed from the deck and used when it's drawn?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan For example you could always remove the first item (`remove(0)`), until the deck is empty. As a separate comment, have you considered using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList? It has a `removeFirst` and `removeLast` methods and could be more efficient for your use case.

Comment: @Hitman47 i don't really understand where to put that code..

Comment: @HaydenHolligan for testing, i just put it in main() and print out the value of the card, and it works for one card, but after seeing others' comments, i think it is worth checking the times you calling thr PlayerCardDraw() method

Comment: Do you have a stack trace/error message for the new code/error you posted? Again it looks like we're missing some code (e.g. what is `card[cardNum].draw()`?).

Comment: well i'm using slick2d so the draw command renders that to the screen(image stuff in a different part). I didn't mention slick2d because I thought the root of the problem was in my deck or card class which doesn't use slick. card[] is simply an array for images and cardNum is an integer meant for printing that card images in the the right order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at your `Deck` class, You have intialized `cards` in constructor so there should not be such an exception(as cards size is 52).

But one thing is possible to get an exception which is `cards is declared public` and `you may have modified it outside class directly`. So arraylist `cards` is of size 0 and you get IllegalArgumentException exception for your method [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

Make `cards` private.

If you have withdrawn all cards then size of arraylist would become 0, which may cause an exception. Add check for 0 as :

```
public Card PlayerCardDraw ()
{
    Random generator = new Random ();
    if(cards.size() > 0) {
        int index = generator.nextInt (cards.size());
        return cards.remove (index);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this fixed the error i'm having but it's still returning null now; trying to fix it.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I would suggest you add a print statement to you `playerCardDraw()` method, just for the purpose of debugging. Add `System.out.println("playerCardDraw() was called. There are now " + cards.size() + " cards left in the deck.");` If, as expected, the number of calls to the method is unexpected, also add a line saying `new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);` Right after the previous debug statement. This way, you can tell from where the method was called.

Answer (score 0):

You might be calling `PlayerCardDraw` method even before a card is added to the list. Means `cards.size()` must be returning a `zero`. So it is `illegal` to generate a random int using a `zero` seed. Hence is the error.

**Refer to**:
***[Random.nextInt( n )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)***

Comment: I was thinking the same, but he needs to go through the Deck constructor which initializes the array.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you keep calling PlayerCardDraw more than 52 times.
Each time, a card is removed from the deck, so the 53:d time, you are trying to draw a card from an empty deck (ie. a deck of size 0) which causes `generator.nextInt(cards.size());` to throw an exception.

However it is not easy to say.
When you are having problems like this and want help, **always show the full stack trace** of the exception. Also, since we cannot see line numbers in code on stackoverflow, be sure to **indicate** in the code exactly at which line the exception occurs.

Comment: I found where that should be happening and I edited my question and posted the code there. It's running a for statement that only runs 4 times, it should reset at 53, not 4 right?